# Android - Destroy and recreate YoutubePlayerFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

I've a ViewPager which contains 2 Fragments. Each Fragment's content should be replaced by a YoutubePlayerFragment (within a FrameLayout of fragment's layout) in this way:

```
    mYoutubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
    mYoutubePlayerFragment.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, context);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.youtube_frame,mYoutubePlayerFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Everything works good. I can do this by a Button (the "play" button). But when I do the same in the second Fragment of the ViewPager, I receive this warm:

```
YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Forcefully created overlay:..helper:..view:null status:
```

So I thought that I need to release the Player from the first Fragment. So I did that first of call the method for a new Player:

```
fm.beginTransaction().remove(mYoutubePlayerFragment).commit();

    mYoutubePlayerFragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mYoutubePlayerFragment).commit();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.youtube_frame, new TabImage());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    FragmentTransaction fxx =  mYoutubePlayerFragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fxx.replace(R.id.youtube_frame, new TabImage());
    fxx.commit();

    mPlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(null);
    mPlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(null);
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
    mYoutubePlayerFragment = null;
```

This is called from the first Fragment to release the first Player. But I've the same error. I'm not able to detach the YoutubeFragment or what? 
Thanks.

Comment: were you able to find a solution?